# HttpNamespaceManager exception on start - Unable to Get Well Known SID

Tags: wcf, session, windows-7, configuration

When I run HttpNamespaceManager - a tool for configuring WCF services permissions I have goth this exception Unable to Get Well Known SID. Is there anybody who knows solution for this issue?

I am guessing that is something with user credentials in my local PC. I have got and the application source code and this SID is taken from the system (I can not forge it).

Best Regards